# Scale text with neighbouring shape size

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, trigonometry

I want to change the height of the following view and have it's contents scale so that the text view height is the same as the height of the circle AND the font scales.

How would I do this?

[image]

```swift
struct LogoView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
            Text("Hello\nthere")
                .font(.system(size: 80))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        LogoView()
//            .frame(height: 150)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out minutes after I posted lol

```
struct LogoView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
            VStack {
                Text("Hello\nthere")
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```